# Disable submit button and display message

Tags: javascript

id like to be able to disable the submit button when the form is submitted, also id like to add a message like ("this may take a while") when the form is submitted.

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="default.asp" onsubmit="return Validate(this);"> 

<p>Select credit card:
    <select tabindex="11" id="CardType"> 
        <option value="AmEx">American Express</option> 
        <option value="CarteBlanche">Carte Blanche</option> 
    </select> 
</p>

<p>Enter number:
    <input type="text" id="CardNumber" maxlength="24" size="24" value="1234" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitbutton" /> 
</p> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `Validate()` function to include disabling the submit button and showing the message:

```
function Validate(f) {
    var isValid = true;
    // do validation stuff
    if (isValid) {
        f.submitbutton.disabled = true;
        document.getElementById("submitMessage").style.display = "block";
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/EjkSV/

Answer (score 1):

Add a simple span or something to your HTML:

```
<span id="waitMessage" style="display: none;">This may take a while....</span>
```

Then on the click event, show that span and disable the button:

In pure javascript:

```
document.getElementById('submitbutton').addEventListener("click", function()
{
     document.getElementById('submitbutton').disabled = true;
     document.getElementById('waitMessage').style.display = 'visible';
}, false);
```

In jQuery:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function()
{
    this.disabled = true;
    $('#waitMessage').show();
});
```

Comment: +1 for offering vanilla JS in addition to that framework everybody seems to like.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you're doing a traditional postback adding a message isn't much use - the browser's going to post and reload the page anyways. (unless of course the postback is so long the browser just spins forever...) but anyways... If you don't mind using jquery,

```
<input type="submit" id="submitbutton"/>
<span style="display:none">This may take a while...</span>

$("#submitbutton").click(function () {
   $(this).next().show();
$(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to disable a submit button onclick since that could stop the submission.

I suggest instead something like this

```
function Validate(theForm) {
  if (.....) {
.
.
.
    return false; // stop submission
  }
  // here we are happy
  document.getElementById("submitbutton").style.display="none";
  document.getElementById("pleaseWait").style.display="";
  return true; 
}

<form id="myform" method="post" action="default.asp" onsubmit="return Validate(this)"> 

<p>Select credit card:
    <select tabindex="11" id="CardType"> 
        <option value="AmEx">American Express</option> 
        <option value="CarteBlanche">Carte Blanche</option> 
    </select> 
</p>

<p>Enter number:
    <input type="text" id="CardNumber" maxlength="24" size="24" value="1234" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitbutton"  /> 
    <span id="pleaseWait" style="display:none">Please wait...</span> 
</p> 

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks again for your help today...ill give that one a go later on tonight.